# Display data from SQL into chart via WCF service

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, charts, highcharts

I'm doing an assignment in inserting and displaying data from SQL into a chart (using Web Form or Highchart) via WCF service. I was able to get the data from SQL to WCF service but I don't know how to display it into a chart. I know using Web Form I can directly bind the data from SQL to the chart but the purpose of the assignment is to display the data via WCF service. Here are my code:
TempService:

```
public DataSet GetTemp()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "server=DUCPC\\SQLEXPRESS;database=Temprature;user=sa;password=123456";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from RoomTemp",con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;


    }
```

Code to bind the data to the chart in Web Form:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TempService.TempServiceClient tsc = new TempService.TempServiceClient();
        DataSet ds = tsc.GetTemp();
        TempChart.DataSource = ds;
        TempChart.DataBind();
    }
```

Of course the above code not working. Can anyone help to fix the code above? Is there a simple way to insert the data into the SQL database? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: when using the debugger if you were to put a breakpoint at this line `return ds;` what is the value of ds in this line `da.Fill(ds);` when you click on the magnifying glass in the `QuickWatch window`? do you see data..? shouldn't you be binding like this perhaps `TempChart.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`

Comment: @MethodMan I checked went run the service and it did return the data in the database in 'return ds;' but binding using the code above 'TempChart.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];' did not help display the data in the chart

Comment: I think that you should look into populating the data into a List<T> and binding it that way.. or look into how to use the .add method overloads when populating the dropdown with the text, key which would be string, integer for example..